# Intertwine all the request to a single one

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, anorm

I want to make a few requests to unrelated tables:

```
def info(a: Int): MyInfo = DB withConnection {
    implicit con =>
      val res = SQL("Select ....")
      val res2 = SQL("Select ...")
      val res3 = SQL("Select ...")
  }
```

Is this a reasonable way to do it? Is there any way to "intertwine" all these request to one and send them as a single request? And also, if I leave this code as it is, will it open 3 different connections or will it be only one single connection?

Answer (score 1):

Something like MS SQL can return multiple result sets but I'd rather keep it as it is and leave this code untouched.

This would not open 3 different connections but use the implicit one you provided. But that sure would be 3 queries to database instead of one.

In general I'd leave it this way unless you are experiencing real performance issues

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to make 3 different queries instead of 1.